# Backbone validate method without a url defined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Model as

```
var Info = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
       name: '',
       email :''
    },
    initialize: function(){
        console.log('Object created');
    },
    validate: function(attr){
         if(!attr.name){
            return 'Name cannot be empty';
         },
         if(!attr.email){
            return 'Email cannot be empty';
         }
    }
});

var model = new Info();
model.set({
    name: '',
    email: ''
});
var viewClass = Backbone.View.extend({
     _modelBind: undefined,
     initialize: function(){
        this._modelBind = new Backbone.ModelBinder();
        this.render();
     },
     render: function(){
        var template = _.template($('#App1').html());
        this.$el.html(template);
        var bindings = {
           name: '[name=name]',
           email: '[name=email]'
        };
        this._modelBind.bind(model, this.el, bindings);
     },
     'events': {
        'click #btnSubmit': 'Submit'
     },
     Submit: function(){
         var response = {
             name: model.get('name'),
             email: model.get('email')
         };
         this.model.save(response);
     }
});
```

html is

```
<script type="text/template" id="App1">
     Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/><br />
     Email: <input type="text" id="email" name="email" /><br />
     <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" />
</script>
```

On `save` event, it goes to `validate` method and after that it goes to the value specified in the `url` attribute of the `model`.

I don't want to specify a `url` parameter. Can i still use `validate` method without url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `validate` directly:

```
var error = this.model.validate(this.model.attributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify url parameter, you will get an error on `this.model.save()`:

> Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified

Comment: That is my question. I do not want to redirect just want to validate on this same page.

Comment: The suggested approach has one disadvantage: 'invalid' event is not triggered if you call validate function directly. I think it's better to call this.model.set({'name': 'name', 'email':email'}, {validate:true}).